# Count of sub-arrays with a given sum such that the indices are in ascending order

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming, sub-array

Given an array, count the number of sub-arrays with a given sum such that the indices are in ascending order (They do not need to be continuous, but the indices of the elements of the array should be in ascending order.)

For example - 
Array - {1 2 3 4 5}, Sum - 5
Then {1,4} is also a valid sub array as the indices are in ascending order (1 < 4). Others are {2,3} etc.

NOTE - This question seems to be very much similar to the question of count of sub-arrays, but it becomes more complicated when it comes to the indices being in ascending order as there will be more values then. I request someone to please share a Pseudo Code for the same and if not possible, share the logic.

Comment: Please someone help me with this, any idea would also be really appreciated

Comment: I request someone to please help me with this problem as soon as possible. I was trying to make the dp for it but got stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to counting the number of subsequences that sum to `sum`. Saying the indices have to be ascending doesn't really mean anything, as long as you don't have repeating indices. Then the problem can be solved with a knapsack-esque dynamic programming approach.

Define `dp[N+1][sum+1]` to store, at `dp[i][j]` the number of subsequences of the array up to (but not including) index `i` that sum to `j`. Python code is as follows:

```
N = 10
sum = 10
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]

dp = [[0 for x in range(sum+1)] for x in range(N+1)]
dp[0][0] = 1  # base case; one way to achieve a sum of 0 taking 0 elements
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(sum+1):
        if j + arr[i] <= sum:
            dp[i+1][j+arr[i]] += dp[i][j]
        dp[i+1][j] += dp[i][j]

print dp[N][sum]
```